# android - hidden field in listview, using custom cursoradapter

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-cursoradapter

In my app I have a listview, which when you click on an item i want a dialogfragment to appear with details in it. The listview is populated using a custom cursoradapter and each row is a view extended from a relativelayout.

My thought process is that i would have some kind of id value in the custom view and when selected, the id is used in a new db query to populate the dialogfragment. However, I don't want the id on view in the row, I want it hidden.

I'm thinking that i create a custom view class, extended from relativelayout, and in the view is a field that will hold the id as well as the two textviews.

My main problem is working out how to use my custom view inside the adapter. Every example i have found, inflates an xml layout inside newview, but my xml layout will not include the id field.

Can I just create a new object for my view, inside newview rather than inflating an xml?

Or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: where you wana use the id ? in onItemClick ? if so there is already id passed to listener there (last `long`) it is a value of `_id` field from the Cursor

Comment: in onItemClick(with CursorAdapter) you can also use `Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` ... now in `c` you have Cursor pointed to selected/cliecked row ... now you can do `var = c.getInt/String/etc(c.getColumnIndex("column that is not showed in item view but is in the cursor"))`

Comment: Yes I want to use the id in onItemClick. This all sounds really promising stuff, let me try now and let you know how i go. If it works, you can post it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Comment: Both examples work perfectly, and though it is handy to be able to access all the cursor info, I think the _id from last long is enough for ,y case. Please add an answer so I can accept

Comment: @Selvin - please put your comments into an answer so I can accept them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with `CursorAdapter` in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` implementation of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` you can get:

1. the `_id` column from the underlying Cursor - simply, it is the `long id` parameter of this function
2. any column visible or not in your item view but existing in the Cursor by casting the item at position to the Cursor like:

   `Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

   Now `c` is pointing to the selected row so you are can get any column from it as simple as `var value = c.getInt/String/etc(c.getColumnIndex("columnname"));`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might be able to use a tag and that would be simpler.

```
view.setTag("myId");
// ...
String id = (String) view.getTag();
```

Comment: Yes I could thanks, but I'm going with the method given by Selvin above. Thanks though