# How to get value of Selected Listview item to String?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a custom ListView, and the data in it comes from SQLite Database.
I have used Cursor and Simple Cursor Adapter to populate the List View.

After setting OnItemClickListener, i cannot get the value of the selected item to string. I have tried lv.getSelectedItemPosition(position) but it is not working.
Can anyone help?

Adapater Class Code

```
public class AllBankBranch_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity macactivity;
ArrayList<all_bankbranch> list2;

public AllBankBranch_adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<all_bankbranch> list){
    super();
    this.macactivity = activity;
    list2 = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list2.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list2.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
private class ViewHolder{

    TextView bankbranchcity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = macactivity.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.engineeringcollbankbranch_listview,null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.bankbranchcity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_enggcoll_bankbranch_city);
    holder.bankbranchcity.setText(list2.get(position).getBankCity());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Retrieving data from Database:

```
 public List<all_bankbranch> getallbank(String city){

    List<all_bankbranch> banklist = new ArrayList<all_bankbranch>();
    String query = "Select BankBranch, BankAddress from all_bankbranch where BankCity = " + city;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            all_bankbranch bbracnh = new all_bankbranch();
            bbracnh.setBankBranch(cursor.getString(2));
            bbracnh.setBankAddress(cursor.getString(3));

            banklist.add(bbracnh);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return banklist;
}
```

MainActivity Code

```
 ListView allbankbranch;
Cursor curbb;
DB_AllBankBranch DABB;
SimpleCursorAdapter scabb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_engg_college_bank_branch);

    DABB = new DB_AllBankBranch(this);
    banksearchbar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_enggcoll_bankbranch_searchbar);
    curbb = DABB.select_bankcity();
    allbankbranch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_enggcoll_bankbranch);

    String[] columns = new String[]{"BankCity"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tv_enggcoll_bankbranch_city};

    scabb = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.engineeringcollbankbranch_listview, curbb, columns, to);
    if (curbb.getCount() > 0) {
        allbankbranch.setAdapter(scabb);
    }
 allbankbranch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


String s = allbankbranch.getItemAtPosition(position);

    }
    });
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the error? What output did you get? Could you post this output? Could you provide some code?

Comment: `getSelectedItemPosition` takes no parameters, and why do you want to get the position if it is passed to `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` method?

Comment: Are you selecting (aka highlighting), or only tapping / clicking?

Comment: Posted the code

Comment: It will provide the list of all cities where the Bank XYZ branch is present, when the user click the city it will guide to the next activity where all the branch of the selected city will be shown..

Comment: After Selecting City the query will be like "SELECT BankBranch, BankAddress from all_bankbranch where BankCity = "City". where the value of the city is from the list view which user select. But i am not getting that value as a string

Comment: Can u throw some more hint on that? please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android - hidden field in listview, using custom cursoradapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237915/android-hidden-field-in-listview-using-custom-cursoradapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
```

{
   String Name =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price_name)).getText().toString();

Log.d("string",Name);

```
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate, It Worked

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectedFromList = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });
```

Use onitem click listener , item selected listener does not work with listview. its only for spinner.

Comment: How does this help the OP, it's exactly the same listener that the OP set.

Comment: Try adding `view.findViewById` in there

Comment: i have used the OnItemClickListener, please refer code

Answer (score -2):

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,long arg3)
        {

           String s = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           //or:
           String ss = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is not working, i already said. Shows Error SQLiteCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score -3):

As Per ur requirement ,

here u go..

If U r row.xml is having multiple views ,,

if u want the particular view assigned data after clicking ur listview position ..

String Name =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price_name)).getText().toString();

U r defined name is having that value,
u will get like this ,,

try ...hope it will work